# Merging the elements of nested arrays into one big array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge the elements of the array into one big array. But I receive a message saying:

```
ReferenceError: reduce is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(reduce(arrays, function(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
    return arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo);
}, 0));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an Array of Arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a method of the `Array` object, so you must use `arrays.reduce()`.

Moreover, since your initial value is set to `0` (the 2nd parameter), you can't use [`arrayOne.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) on it, since it's not an array, so you must set the initial value to `[]`.

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(arrayOne, arrayTwo){
    return arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo);
}, []));
```

Note that calling `Array.flat` is easier:

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
// If you expect a multi-level nested array, you should increase the depth.
var depth = 1;

console.log(arrays.flat(depth));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is only defined on Arrays, you cannot call it by itself:

```
arrays.reduce(
   function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); }
);
// Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```